# The right digit of 4th power of any natural number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that the 4th power of any natural number has a right digit of 0,1,5 or 6.

Comment: *You* should prove it. You might think of a mod that isolates the last digit, and then work in that modular system. This reduces the problem to a finite one, namely the size of that mod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using congruent modulo 10 $$x \equiv 0,1,2,3,...,8,9 \,\ (mod \,\ 10)$$ or,
$$x \equiv 0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm4,\pm5 \,\ (mod \,\ 10)$$ or,
$$x^2 \equiv 0,1,4,9,16,25 \,\ (mod \,\ 10)$$ or,
$$x^2 \equiv 0,1,4,9,6,5 \,\ (mod \,\ 10)$$ or,
$$x^2 \equiv 0,\pm1,4,5,6 \,\ (mod \,\ 10)$$ or,
$$x^4 \equiv 0,1,16,25,36 \,\ (mod \,\ 10)$$ or,
$$x^4 \equiv 0,1,6,5,6 \,\ (mod \,\ 10)$$ or,
$$x^4 \equiv 0,1,6,5 \,\ (mod \,\ 10)$$
$=>$ the rightmost digit of $x^4$ is either $0,1,6$ or $5$.

Answer (score 1):

For the last digit of a product, you have to know only the last digits of the factors. Considering fourth powers, you only have 10 cases:

- 1: $1^4 = 1$
- 2: $2^4 = 16$
- 3: $3^4 = 81$
- 4: $4^4 = 256$
- 5: $5^4 = 625$
- 6: $6^4 = 1296$
- 7: $7^4 = 2401$
- 8: $8^4 = 4096$
- 9: $9^4 = 6561$
- 0: $0^4 = 0$

Looking at the last digits of these numbers, you see that only 0, 1, 5 and 6 appear. The last digits of these numbers *have* to be the last digit of any fourth power, for the reason stated above.

Answer (score 0):

When multiplying numbers, the last digit of a product can be determined by the last digits of the terms being multiplied.

You know that the rightmost digit of the product of 26^4 will be 6, because the result of 6^4 has a rightmost digit of 6. That said, we just have to prove that all the numbers from 0-9, when raised to the 4th power, has a rightmost digit of 0,1,5, or 6.

You could do this simply by using cases:

right digit of 0^4 = 0

right digit of 1^4 = 1

right digit of 2^4 = 6

right digit of 3^4 = 1

...

right digit of 9^4 = 1